# Match various urls with ids to urls with placeholders

Tags: php, regex

I have two arrays of urls: ArrayA and ArrayB. I need to know which urls (there can be several occurrences of the same url) from ArrayB match to which url from ArrayA (urls here are unique).

I will go over ArrayB with a foreach loop and try to match the urls.

ArrayA contains urls like:

- clients/{client_id}/projects/{project_id}
- clients/{client_id}
- activities/{activity_id}
- activities/{activity_id}/edit

ArrayB contains urls like:

- *clients/123/projects/23*
- *clients/5/projects/12*
- *clients/1*
- *clients/52*
- *activities/52*
- *activities/35*
- *activities/52/edit*
- *activities/35/edit*

I want to match each url in ArrayB to the correct url in ArrayA and immediately perform operations on it if a match found (so no need to save anything). A route in ArrayB always matches only one Route in ArrayA (so a n:1 relationship).

```php
$arrayA = getPossibleRoutes();
$arrayB = getActivatedRoutes();

// YOUR CODE
```

I hope to make a foreach loop (with a nested one most likely) that iterates over ArrayA or ArrayB and perform an operation as soon as a match is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
foreach($arrayA as $item){
        $patterns[$item] = preg_replace(['/(\{\w*\})/','/\//'],['\d+','\/'],$item);
}

foreach ($arrayB as $arr) {
        foreach($patterns as $route => $pattern){
                if (preg_match('/^'.$pattern.'$/', $arr))
                {
                        //the matched route is $route
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
    $arrayA = [
    "clients/{client_id}",
    "activities/{activity_id}",
    "activities/{activity_id}/edit",
    "test/{test}/test",
    "random/random/{random_id}",
    "clients/{client_id}/projects/{project_id}",
    "unmatched/path",
];

$arrayB = [
    "clients/123/projects/23",
    "clients/5/projects/12",
    "clients/1",
    "clients/52",
    "activities/52",
    "random/random/1",
    "activities/35",
    "activities/52/edit",
    "test/1/test",  
    "activities/35/edit",
    "not_found_url/35"
];

foreach($arrayA as $arr) {
    $key = substr_count($arr, '/');
    $getFirstWord = explode("/",$arr);
    $sortedA[$getFirstWord[0]][$key] = $arr;

}

foreach($arrayB as $arr) {
    $getFirstWord = explode("/",$arr);
    if(array_key_exists($getFirstWord[0],$sortedA)) {
        $urls[$arr] = $sortedA[$getFirstWord[0]][substr_count($arr, '/')];
    }
}


foreach($urls as $key => $url)
  print_r($key." => ".$url."<br>");

?>
```

And the output will be:

```
clients/123/projects/23 => clients/{client_id}/projects/{project_id}
clients/5/projects/12 => clients/{client_id}/projects/{project_id}
clients/1 => clients/{client_id}
clients/52 => clients/{client_id}
activities/52 => activities/{activity_id}
random/random/1 => random/random/{random_id}
activities/35 => activities/{activity_id}
activities/52/edit => activities/{activity_id}/edit
test/1/test => test/{test}/test
activities/35/edit => activities/{activity_id}/edit
```

EDIT: This code should be now, dynamic for any number of urls/paths. It also supports not found urls and/or paths.
EDIT 2: optimizations

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly this doesn't work anymore when the routes have the same number of segments. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sadly your answer isn't dynamic enough for my program. The routes can have any kind or number of words/elements in them.

Comment: Edited my answer once more :)

Comment: This is great, thanks. Sadly I have to little points to upvote you.